# PostgreSQL- get records with unique column combination

Tags: postgresql, unique, distinct

I want to select the records that have a unique column combination in postgresql, however it doesn't seem to work with distinct as distinct only removes duplicates.

Example

```
ID  A  B 
01  1  2
02  1  2
03  1  3
04  2  4
05  1  4
06  2  4
07  2  5
08  1  3
```

In this example row with ID 05 and 07 have unique combination AB, how can i get these records

```
SELECT ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select t.* from tablename t
where not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where id <> t.id and a = t.a and b = t.b
)
```

Or with `COUNT()` window function:

```
select t.id, t.a, t.b
from (
  select *, count(id) over (partition by a, b) counter
  from tablename
) t  
where t.counter = 1
```

Or with aggregation:

```
select max(id) id, a, b
from tablename
group by a, b
having count(id) = 1
```

Or with a self `LEFT` join that excludes the matching rows:

```
select t.*
from tablename t left join tablename tt
on tt.id <> t.id and tt.a = t.a and tt.b = t.b
where tt.id is null
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=f6133fea794e8808e7406e2cc0483b74).
Results:

```
| id  | a   | b   |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 05  | 1   | 4   |
| 07  | 2   | 5   |
```